# Remedy for breach of contract with a "No Assignment" clause

Tags: contract-law, breach-of-contract

It is common for written contracts between entities to contain a "No Assignment" clause, which essentially states that, for a contract between entities *A* and *B*, the benefits or rights under the contract *A* cannot be assigned to another entity *C* without the consent of *B*.

It is possible for a breach of contract by *B* to precipitate the dissolution of *A*.  (Examples: If *B* poaches a key member of *A*, or if the existence of *A* as a going concern depends entirely on its contract with *B*.)  In such an event, it appears that a "No Assignment" clause would in effect make *B* immune to any liability claims, because *A* no longer exists and the contract could not be assigned to any beneficiary of *A*.

Not a perfect analogy, but in playground terms this is sort of like Bob and Al agreeing, "Let's build a sandcastle.  But (here's the No Assignment clause) your friends don't get to play with it unless I agree."  Once the sandcastle is complete Bob kills Al (yeah, it's a tough playground).  Per the contract, Bob can invite all his friends to play and reject all of Al's friends.

**Is there a legal doctrine that prevents a scenario like this?**

I.e., can a contract clause indirectly render a contract party immune to liability for that party's breach of contract?  I have a notion that there is something like the obverse of the "unclean hands" doctrine that would prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a legal doctrine that prevents a scenario like this?

Yes. The particulars of the scenario would determine the grounds on which a non-assignment clause would be null and void. The [*Restatement (Second) of Contracts*](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) roughly classifies these alternative grounds for unenforceability as grounds of *undue influence* and of *public policy*. Additionally, by default a non-assignment clause "*does not forbid assignment of a right to damages for breach of the whole contract*". See *Restatement* at § 322(2)(a). Invoking this principle seems pertinent where, *inter alia*, a party breaches the *covenant of good faith and fair dealing*.

In the scenarios outlined in the 2nd paragraph of your question (i.e., *B* poaching a key member of *A*, or *A*'s existence depending entirely on its contract with *B*), the contract is voidable by *A* if *A* "*is justified in assuming that [B] will not act in a manner inconsistent with [A's] welfare*", Restatement at § 177(1) (brackets added).

Although *undue influence* typically involves some sort of fiduciary duty that is unlikely to exist in an arm's-length agreement between *A* and *B*, the *Restatement* certainly elaborates in terms of *domination*. That choice of term affords to *A* the argument that *B*'s abuse of its domination warrants voiding the non-assignment clause insofar as it frustrates *A*'s ultimate purpose of entering that contract.

In the playground scenario, *B*'s intentional killing of the counterparty with whom *B* partnered constitutes serious and deliberate misconduct that renders the clause unenforceable on grounds of public policy. See *Restatement* at § 178(3)(c). Moreover, the connection between the killing and the non-assignment clause would be evident as to timing and motive, *Id* at (d).

Lastly, notwithstanding the premise of "*breach of the **whole** contract*" (emphasis added) in *Restatement* at § 322(2)(a), the multiple references to "*grant[ing] relief as justice requires*" and similar phrases suggest that other principles would supersede said premise in order to preempt an absurd outcome. That is, the interests of justice would outweigh *B*'s allegation that his compliance with other portions of the contract should bar an assignment [to *A*'s beneficiaries] of a right to damages.